# query.getresultlist() in jpa showing 2 queries fired in my console

Tags: hibernate, jpa

QueryImpl( SELECT phContact from phContact PhoneContact  left join fetch phContact.phContactName phContactName  where phContactName.phNumber in (:pphNumbers)       and phContactName.NameGroupIndicator = :pNameGroup       and phContactName.primaryName = :pPrimaryName  and phContact.status in (:pphContactStatusType)  order by phContact.phContactId asc, phContact.dateRange.effectiveDate desc,phContact.status asc,   phContact.dateRange.expirationDate desc )

above is the query that i passed into the entity manager , I have switched ON SQL traces and seen query got fired twice.

Could anyone help me out the reason why it got fired twice ?

Comment: format your code. post the code that executes the query. post the SQL invoked (and the rest of that section of the log), ...

Comment: aQuery = super
                                .getEntityManager()
                                .createNamedQuery(here my named query was passed) . 
there is no log to show here , but when i monitored query execution , I have noticed that it fired twice . Named Query is nothing apart from which i mentioned above...

Comment: Put all of that in your QUESTION, and yes there is a log, the one provided by your JPA provider.